# C:\ file scan with C++, access denied to specific files

Tags: c++, windows

Ok so I have written a code with recursive function that scans my (or any other) C:\ disc. 
Using chdir() I'm changing the active directory to C:\ and using system("dir >> C:\Test\"filename") to get the files in that directory written in .txt and then reading it to know what I have. After that I'm checking for additional directories with `temp.substr("<DIR>")` and calling the function again just with longer path for that specific directory.

The code itself works as it should but I've ran to some directories that I can't access such as Administrator or specific folders in Windows. The only way I've found around them is by adding exeptions to the code so that it just avoids those folders. I'd like to know if there is a way to get a list of folders/files that I don't have access to from cmd since it would make my code a lot more precise or a way to access those directories.

Comment: perhaps "run as administrator"? C++ doesn't know "access privileges". In terms of file I/O, either the file is visible to the program or not.

Comment: Exactly as it should be. If you do not have the right access permisions for the files, you should not be able to see those files - whether your program is written in C, C++, Java, Basic, Assember or Fortran, or for that matter a batch file or a powershell script. I'd be HIGHLY disappointed with the security of the OS if there was a trivial way around that. Obviously, you could write some more clever code that simply makes a note that a directory is "protected". But ultimately, if you haven't got the rights, the OS _should_ prevent you from accessing the file.

Comment: Win 8.1 is a bit weird regarding access rights but I am an admin, anyway what I'd like to know is if there is a function or an algorithm to see what I can't access and just to avoid a whole bunch of it alltogather

Comment: So what actually happens when you try to list the contents of these directories?  If the call to chdir() fails, it should return -1; you can detect this and skip the directory in question.  If the call to chdir() succeeds but the `dir` command doesn't, the output should contain no files or directories; you could use the absence of `.` and `..` as a sign that this has happened, or if you do nothing the inaccessible directory will behave as if it were empty, which is probably as appropriate a result as any.

Comment: I didn't even know what those . and .. were so I was just skipping them in my output text file :/, but thanks I'll change the code to check for chdir() return value. Edit: What happens is that the next recursion call gets bugged and just keeps adding the same line of text like...C:\User\AdminAdminAdminAdmin....and so on.

Answer (score 1):

While C++ file API does not have any idea about file permissions and such other than you'll fall when you try to read a file you don't have permissions to, C++ do have access to the Windows API. The Windows API are system calls that gives you access to native OS functionalities, such as calls to [GetFileSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446639%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Note that using Windows API means your code would need to take extra steps to ensure portability if you want to run it on non Windows platforms.

Comment: I have some experience with Windows API using C++ but I didn't go as far to make it a real program, it was just for practice. Is there a function in Windows.h that I could use instead?

Answer (score 0):

The process (your program) runs with certain privileges, normally the users one. The access rights in Windows aren't as simple as "Administrator is god". Even if your user account is member of the "Administrators" group, you can not simply access everything. It usually depends if the OWNER of a file system object grants privileges to other groups and users.

A member of the "Administrators" group might be able to gain access by overriding security settings, but I would advise against that.

You might need elevated privileges and even might need to run your application under a SYSTEM account, it very much depends on what you are trying to achieve.

For more details I suggest to read the "Best practices for Security API" here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717796(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717796%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

and especially the chapter "Running with Special Privileges".

Comment: I'm trying to get a list of all files I CAN'T access so I can add all those exeptions to my code. Since with my current exeptions I'm avoiding a lot of files that I actually can read.